# Clicking on LI link using Selenium Webdriver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

New to Selenium here. Thanks for the help in advance! (**Solved**)

I've had success at clicking on links using the code below, but having a hard time clicking on links under LI. I've referenced a couple of other stackoverflow pages, but have yet to find a solution.

In this case, I am trying to click on the page number "2", and then run my scraper (which I have working for page 1) for all subsequent pages. Note that clicking on page 2 will cause a change in the table (aka, a new set of stock tickers and information gets pulled up), but the website link itself will not change.

Website link: https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary

Here is what I am trying to click on:
[The number 2, highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQPwt.png)

What I see when I inspect the element: [inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCnJl.png)

I can click on a different link (titled "Can Aggregated Insider Trading Activities Predict the Market?" on the same page via code below, but when I input "2" instead, I get an error message, "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"2"}"

**In summary**, I would like to "click" on page 2, and bring up more stock information, and then run my scraper through it (then use a for loop for the rest of the pages). I won't have any troubles creating the for loop to scrape multiple pages, but I can't seem to get Selenium to click on the next page for me.

### Solved Code - thanks for all the help everyone!

```
   from selenium import webdriver
    
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

   import time

   PATH = "C:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\Webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe"
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

   driver.get("https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary")

   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='el-pager']/li[text()='2']").click

    try:
       element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='el-pager']/li[text()='2']"))
)
       element.click() 
    except:
        driver.quit()
```

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share with us the code you tried so far that attempts to click on the link '2', and the results/errors that it yielded. Also please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @piterbarg thank you for the suggestion, does that help?

Comment: what exactly do you want to extract from this site?

Comment: @Vin If you click on page "2" from that link, it will refresh the table in regards to stock ticker information. I already have a scraper to scrape the first page, so my goal is to be able to "click" on the next page (in this case two), and refresh the table with new tickers, scrape it, and go onto the next page etc.

Comment: @Vin I won't have any trouble creating a for loop for scraping subsequent pages - I just need help getting Selenium to click on the page 2 link (and all subsequent pages). Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because page '2' is not a "link text". If you will notice 'Can Aggregated Insider Trading Activities Predict the Market?" is link text because its tag is "a". Add this to click on your page 2
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='el-pager']/li[text()='2']").click`

Comment: hmmm I tried that and I didn't get an error code, which is good! However, when I look at the page itself, its still on page 1. If one were to physically click on page 2, the table with tickers changes at the bottom.

Comment: Did you add wait after the click? What's your next script after the click?

Comment: ah, there was an error in my wait after the click, it now works! Thanks a ton! I'll edit my question with the right code for others in case they need it in the future.